# $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}y^{1.5}$ Show that f is differentiable at (0,0).

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let f be defined by $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x}y^{1.5}$ Show that f is differentiable at (0,0).

I have calculated partial derivatives the normal way which didn't help me. Then I tried first principles:

$g_x(x,y)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h,0)-g(0,0)}{h} = \frac{0-0}{h} = 0$

Similarly for the $y$ partial derivative. But I am unsure where to proceed from here.

Thanks

Comment: What's differentiablity definition?

Comment: From the classes notebook: Function is differentiable if it admits a linear approximation at a point c. In this case (0,0) with the error term e(c,h)/||h|| -> 0 as h-> 0

Comment: So, did you try with it?

Comment: First, something is fishy with the domain here. Ordinarily we only talk about differentiability when the function is defined on an open neighborhood of the point.

Comment: Good point @TedShifrin The function is only defined for $x,y\ge 0.$ The problem is a nonstarter without further information.

Answer (score 1):

For differentiablity at $(0,0)$ we have
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|y|\sqrt{xy}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\leq \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{|y|}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$

Comment: @TedShifrin Please check my edit!

Comment: Yeah, this is better. I still complain that we need $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ for the function to be defined, so is this really a valid limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$?

Comment: Why not in it's domain. I think the function is continuous in $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$.

Comment: Sure, but, as I said above, ordinarily to discuss differentiability, one must be at an interior point of the domain.

Comment: @TedShifrin As we see, formulas show this function is differentiable in $(0,0)$ but it's derivative $f_x=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}y^{1.5}$ shows a infinity value there. Is that compatible with what we found?

Comment: It's definitely not $C^1$, but so what? The partial derivatives at the origin are both 0 (you used that in your first limit).

Comment: @TedShifrin is correct. This function should not be accepted as differentiable at $(0,0)$ with its restricted domain, without some extra clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The existence of the two partial derivatives at **(0, 0)** does not prove differentiability there. You would need to be able to prove the continuity of the partial derivatives in some neighborhood of **(0, 0)**.

Comment: This is wrong, actually. $C^1$ in a neighborhood is a *sufficient*, but *not* a *necessary* condition for differentiability at the point.